# "The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly." after upgrading web app from .NET 3.5 to 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm attempting to move from VS2008 to VS2010 and want to also upgrade the website to .NET 4.0.  I've copied the source over and ran the conversion wizard with no errors.  There were also no compile errors as well.  However, right when the page loads I get the exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
  Message=The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Reflection.Emit.InternalAssemblyBuilder.get_Location()
       at CoreLab.Common.o.a(Assembly A_0)
       at CoreLab.Common.v.a(LicenseContext A_0, Type A_1, String& A_2, String& A_3, String& A_4)
       at CoreLab.Common.v.a(LicenseContext A_0, Type A_1, String& A_2, Boolean& A_3, String& A_4, String& A_5)
       at CoreLab.Common.v.a(LicenseContext A_0, Type A_1, Boolean A_2)
       at CoreLab.Oracle.OracleProviderFactory.CreateConnection()
       at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetStoreConnection(DbProviderFactory factory)
       at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
       at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateEntityConnection(String connectionString)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(String connectionString, String defaultContainerName)
       at VZW.TrainingPortfolioManager.Entity.TPMEntities..ctor(String connectionString) in C:\TPM_NET4\Entity\TPMEntities.Designer.cs:line 114
       at VZW.TrainingPortfolioManager.Website.Global.Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\TPM_NET4\Website\Global.asax.cs:line 110
       at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.RaiseOnStart(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.CompleteAcquireState()
       at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
  InnerException:
```

The error happens in code auto-generated by the ADO.NET Entities Framework in the constructor:

```
/// <summary>
/// Initialize a new TPMEntities object.
/// </summary>
public TPMEntities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString, "TPMEntities")
{
    OnContextCreated();
}
```

The exception happens when calling into the base constructor.

Was there some changes made in the entity framework for .NET 4.0 that would require me to do something different or change anything?  I'm pretty much at a loss here.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at, http://elegantcode.com/2010/01/28/the-entity-framework-and-the-the-invoked-member-is-not-supported-in-a-dynamic-assembly-exception

Comment: That's a pretty general error. What namespaces are you using?

Comment: This is a bug in `CoreLab.Common`; they need to check that the assembly isn't dynamic.

Comment: @George - Yea I did run across that article as well.  I tried fully qualifying the assembly in the connection string but it made no difference.

Comment: @SLaks - Is there a newer version that works on .NET 4?  Why did this work on 3.5, does the 3.5 Entity Framework generate assmeblies in some different way?

Comment: I have no idea; what's `CoreLab`? This has nothing to do with EF; the problem is that something (perhaps LINQ) has generated a dynamic assembly.

Comment: CoreLab is the Oracle driver I'm using.  I guess the crash is in there somewhere.

Comment: CoreLab was the name of an ADO.NET provider for Oracle... IIRC they renamed this a long time (2 or 3 years when V 5 came out) ago to Devart... the Devart components are currently at V 6.5 (with really nice EF and Linq integration even with CTP) - which version are you using ?

Comment: Yup, this project was using 4.75 or something.  Ouch.  I take no blame though, I was just hired a couple weeks ago to resurrect this project from the depths of oblivion, and most everything about it is pretty ancient.  I upgraded to 6.5 and the program magically went away.  Yahia, if you submit this feedback as an answer I'll go "Accept" it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue ended up being due to a bug in the version of the Oracle database driver I was using.  I confirmed this with DevArt, and obtained a new version which fixes this bug.